# Assigning value to variables in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer doesn't bind data if we assign value to polymer multiple times.

For example:

```
Polymer({
  is: "g-feed",
  properties: {
    event: String
  },
  ready: ()=> {
    var self = this;
    self.news = [];

    var nws = [];
    nws.push({nm:'One'});
    nws.push({nm:'Two'});
    self.news = nws;

    nws.push({nm:'One1'});
    nws.push({nm:'Twoa'});
    self.news = nws;

    console.log(self.news);
  }
});
```

Here the news array would only hold the values "one" and "two" rendered on the webpage.

Can you please tell me why this happens and how to overcome this. Also, how to work with consistantly changing data in polymer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `self.set('news', nws)` instead of `self.news = nws`? Any why use a copy of `this` in `self`?

Comment: Which version of polymer are you using?